# Ubuntu only starts with black screen on current kernel version (5.11.0-25-generic)

Tags: boot, kernel, display

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP Elitebook G5, but I have got the problem that it only shows a black screen after startup (after showing the GRUB Manager). When I connect an external display to the laptop, it is working like normal but the internal screen still does not show any image. If I boot the laptop with an older Kernel Version (i.e. 5.8.0-55-generic) then the internal screen is working again.

Could this be related to a driver issue?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: One option you have is to revert to the GA kernel stack (ie. assuming you're on 20.04 LTS, the GA stack uses the 5.4 kernel which is supported the entire life of the product). You can have both GA & HWE stack installed; giving you an option when newer HWE kernels give issues - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried the steps which were described in the link you have provided and now the internal screen is working again like normal. :) The only thing I have noticed is that I am now running with an older kernel version than before (5.4.0-81-generic). Is there still a way to update it or could there be some sort of security risk with this version?

Comment: There are NO security risks with the GA kernel; all security patches are updated to it (and it's secure given it's patched, unlike using the now *unsupported* 5.8 kernel you were using.  The GA (5.4) kernel is the default for servers, as it's seen as the *stable* choice; the HWE is for desktops which may need *newer* kernels for new video graphic stacks.  There is **no security risk** with using the GA stack.

Comment: Ok, good to hear. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide this *work around* that I gave in comments; but it doesn't resolve the issue and keep the HWE kernel stack.

Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices:

- GA (*general*) , or
- HWE (*hardware enablement*).

One option you have is to revert to the GA kernel stack (*ie. assuming you're on 20.04 LTS; you didn't say*). The GA stack uses the 5.4 kernel which is supported the entire life of the product.

You can have both GA & HWE stack installed; giving you an option when newer HWE kernels give issues; meaning you can now and again try the HWE stack and in time the issue will hopefully be resolved :)

For details on stacks & reverting from HWE to GA, please see (search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*"

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

There are NO security risks with the GA kernel; all security patches are updated to it (and it's secure given it's patched, unlike using the now *unsupported* 5.8 kernel you were using. The GA (5.4) kernel is the default for servers, as it's seen as the *stable* choice; the HWE is for desktops which may need newer kernels for new video graphic stacks.

Comment: To contradict my NO security risks, in a prior release Ubuntu have announced some fixes were only being applied to the HWE stack (not GA) for a LTS release; however that release was in it's last month of support anyway; so most users should have been upgrading then anyway (I'm also here not referring to a critical package either.. a package now only available in 'universe').